# Formatting data using python

Tags: python

I would like to parse the data with 'tab delimited' and would like to replace certain string in the data.

input file:
vi foo.txt:

```
Bob lives in%3a Boston
Sam lives    in Houston
Jay       lives in Ruston
Bill        lives in           Atlanta
```

This is what I came up with:
vi foo.py:

```
import re

fin = open("foo.txt")
fout =  open("bar.txt", "w")
for line in fin.readlines():
    fout.write('\t'.join(line.split())+'\n') # parse data with tab delimited

for line in fin.readlines():
    fout.write(re.sub('%3a',':',line)) # substitute string with regex
```

vi bar.txt:

```
Bob lives   in%3a   Boston
Sam lives   in  Houston
Jay lives   in  Ruston
Bill    lives   in  Atlanta
```

Why is %3a still in output rather than ':'?

Thanks,

Rio

Comment: I dont know what you are looking to do with 2 loops, but you need to reset the file pointer before the second loop with a `fin.seek(0)` , then you will see 8 lines instead of 4 - the first set would have `%3a`, and second would have a `:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readlines()` is an iterator. Once you consume it - it's no more. You are consuming it on the first call to `for line in fin.readlines():`. On the second call - there's nothing to iterate over anymore, so this line: `fout.write(re.sub('%3a',':',line))` is never called.

Even if it did - it would have created two copies of the input data in the output - one tab delimited but with `%3a`, and one not tab delimited but without `%3a`.

What you want to do is this:

```
for line in fin.readlines():
    fout.write('\t'.join(re.sub('%3a',':',line).split())+'\n')
```

Comment: I did not see he's called `readlines()` twice. Your answer is correct. And by the way, `re` is too heavy for a simple string replacing in his case.

Comment: Thanks! How can I achieve it with 2 for loops as I tried before? I want the code to be more readable and I have many strings to substitute.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 This might be true, but it's not the epitome of the issues with his code.

Comment: @Rio I don't tink that more loops are more readable - on the contrary. However, if you do want to implement more than one loop - you need each loop to take as *input* the *output* of the loops before that.

Comment: If I have multiple patterns to be replaced e.g. %3a as :, %3f as ? how can I achieve it? Thanks